# WPF One Way Binding broken

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm

Im trying to bind 2 different WPF controls to the same property in the ViewModel, a CheckBox.IsChecked and an Expander.IsExpanded. The behavior I want to achieve is to have the CheckBox affect the ViewModel (and therefore the Expander as well), but not the other way bound.
Something like:

```
Checkbox Checked -> ViewModel property set to frue -> Expander.Expand
Checkbox Unchecked -> ViewModel property set to false -> Expander.Collapse
Expander Expanded -> Nothing else affected
Expander Collapsed -> Nothing else affected
```

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Expander.Header>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="Is Checked"/>
        </Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Expanded!"/>
    </Expander>
</Window>
```

and the Code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication9
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange("IsChecked");
            }
        }

        protected void NotifyPropertyChange(string PropertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, as soon as I click on the Expander to expand / collapse it, the Binding seems to stop working. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how do I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**New Answer**

Discovered you could do this by setting your `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` on your Expander. This keeps the binding as Two-Way, but never updates the Source since you're telling it not to update the source unless you explicitly tell it to.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
    <Expander.Header>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="Is Checked"/>
    </Expander.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Expanded!"/>
</Expander>
```

Leaving my old answer below so the comments make sense, and because I still feel there is no problem with view-specific code going in the code-behind of a view :)

---

**Old Answer**

Personally since this is View-Specific code, I see no problem with using a CheckBox click event to set the Expander's `IsExpanded` value.

```
private void MyCheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyExpander.IsExpanded = ((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

You could make this even more generic by removing the names and navigating the Visual Tree to find the Expander associated with the CheckBox. Here's an example using some [Visual Tree Helpers I built](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/)

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    var expander = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<Expander>(chk);

    if (expander != null)
        expander.IsExpanded = chk.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Im creating a view with at least 6 Expanders with Checkboxes on their headers. Its too much code, and I prefer not using any code at all because it reduces the flexibility of the view.

Comment: @HighCore If you've got multiple Expanders/CheckBoxes, you probably have a default style for them and could set the Click event as an EventSetter in the style. I would use something to navigate the visual tree to find the Expander associated with that CheckBox and you wouldn't need to use named values at all.

Comment: @HighCore See my updated answer. It works without any code-behind

Comment: (Old Answer) I think it's a bad idea to do in the code behind with an event.  It leads to messy code - especially if you are trying to follow an MVVM pattern (Recommended).  Navigating the visual tree should be avoided as well as it can cause performance hits depending on the size of the tree.

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit worked perfectly. Had 5 sliders, one called "(all)" and then Top, Right, Bottom, Left (for pixel sizes, like CSS border's).  If (all) is changed, it should always push the values down over the other 4, but the other 4 should never influence (all).  Thank you!

Comment: You are awesome. I just hit this exact same problem when binding the IsExpanded property of an Expander to a "HasErrors" dependency property of a class in my ViewModel. TwoWay binding caused the expander to set HasErrors, and OneWay binding caused the UI to not update. Your approach forces OneWay binding to work properly in this scenario. I owe you a pint!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the checkbox to affect the expander (but not vice versa) then bind the expander normally and use `OneWayToSource` on the checkbox:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsChecked}">
      <Expander.Header>
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Content="Is Checked"/>
      </Expander.Header>
      <TextBlock Text="Expanded!"/>
   </Expander>
</Window>
```

Using `OneWayToSource` on the checkbox will allow it to:

- modify the underlying property (and therefore affect the expander, which is also bound to that property)
- not be affected by other components that make changes to the underlying property

Comment: I cannot do this because the checkbox is the primary data representation here. It should always reflect the value in the ViewModel.

Comment: @HighCore I was about to +1 this until I thought of that, so figured I'd wait. Nice solution though if that isn't needed.

Comment: According to MSDN, the default mode for check boxes is generally TwoWay, but have you tried writing it explicitly? "{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: @RenaudDumont That would just make the CheckBox check/uncheck when the expander expands/collapses, which is not the desired behavior

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Yes, but using the code posted in this answer, adding that to the CheckBox would cause the CheckBox to check/uncheck when the expander expands/collapses, because the Expander is bound by a TwoWay binding to the same value

Comment: @Rachel It's not very clear, but I think Renaud intended for that code to be applied to the question's binding, rather than Nate Kohl's answer. It makes no sense applied to Nate's answer, since his key point is about `OneWayToSource` and the comment talks about the default binding state. Your response is accurate, though. I've ended up very confused about what that comment could mean. In any case, it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid any code-behind, you can add a degree of separation between the `Expander` and `CheckBox` states in your ViewModel:

```
            private bool _isChecked;
            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return _isChecked; }
                set
                {
                    _isChecked = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChange("IsChecked");
                    IsExpanded = value;
                }
            }

            private bool _isExpanded;
            public bool IsExpanded
            {
                get { return _isExpanded; }
                set
                {
                    _isExpanded = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChange("IsExpanded");
                }
            }

    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}">
        <Expander.Header>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="Is Checked" x:Name="cb"/>
        </Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Expanded!"/>
    </Expander>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of this as a last resort.